# No overload for method 'Main_Calculations' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, overloading

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        int choice;
        choice = 0;

        double length;
        length = 0.00;

        double height;
        height = 0.00; //initiating variables

        double base1;
        base1 = 0.00;

        double width;
        width = 0.00;

        double radius;
        radius = 0.00;

        double total;
        total = 0.00;

        Console.WriteLine("What shape would you like to make?");
        Console.WriteLine("Please select one option (1, 2, 3, or 4)");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Square.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Triangle.");          //menu on the console 
        Console.WriteLine("3. Rectangle.");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Circle.");

        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great! You chose Square.");
            Console.WriteLine("Let's help you calculate the area of a square.");
            Console.WriteLine("But first, we need to know the length of this square");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the length(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine:");
            length = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great! You chose Triangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Let's help you calculate the area of a triangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("But first, we need to know the base and height of this triangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the base(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine):");
            base1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                                          //writing to the console depending on what choice
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the height(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine):");
            height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great! You chose Rectangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Let's help you calculate the area of a rectangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("But first, we need to know the width and height of this rectangle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the width(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine):");
            width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the height(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine):");
            height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great! You chose Circle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Let's help you calculate the area of a circle.");
            Console.WriteLine("But first, we need to know the radius of this circle.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the radius(Integer, or Decimal value is just fine:"); 
            radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        }



        Main_Calculations(args, total, base1, height, width, choice); //Sending Paramters to the next method
    }
    static void Main_Calculations(string[] args, double base1, double height, double width, double total, int choice) //bringing in parameters 
    {



        if(choice == 2)
        {
            total = (base1 * height) * 0.5; //Calculations for triangle

            Console.WriteLine("The area of a triangle is: " + total);
        }

        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            total = width * height; //calculations for rectangle

            Console.WriteLine("The area of a rectangle is: " + total);
        }


           Main_Calculations(choice, total); //Sending Paramters to the next method
    }

        static void Main_Calculations(double length, double radius, double total, double choice)
        {


        if(choice == 1)
        {
            total = length * length; //Calculations for square

            Console.WriteLine("The area of a square is: " + total);
        }

        else if(choice == 4)
        {
            total = (radius * radius) * 3.14; //calculations for circle

            Console.WriteLine("The area of a circle is " + total); //prints the answer to the console
        }


        }
    }
}
```

My 2nd sender for (Math_Calculations) is giving me an error for no overload takes 2 arguments, I don't understand why it won't work the way I have it. Seems possibly I am just missing one phrase, I have stepped in and out of the code looking to now avail.

Comment: Because there is "No overload for method 'Main_Calculations' takes 2 arguments". You have `Main_Calculations(double length, double radius, double total, double choice)` and `Main_Calculations(string[] args, double base1, double height, double width, double total, int choice)`

Comment: Well, there's also `static void Main_Calculations(double length, double radius, double total, double choice)` - but again, that doesn't have two parameters...

Comment: How do i go about fixing this?

Comment: One solution is to simply make some of the arguments of your Main_Calculations optional. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the 2nd method Math_Calculations, you only give 2 arguments to the method when you ask in the method for 4 arguments
So, What you need to do is or, you give 2 arguments extra to the 2dn Math_Calculations call, OR you remove 2 arguments from the method.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to answer with line numbers, but you call

Main_Calculations(choice,total);

when there is no method for Main_Calculations that takes two arguments.Just as Habib has pointed out.